# Form inside Material UI dialog call submit of the form outside dialog

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a form inside a form, The `<form/>` inside form is rendered as Material UI dialog and rendered to DOM in a different portal.

```
/* SPDX-FileCopyrightText: 2021 @koistya */
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT */

import * as React from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  Stack,
  TextField,
  Typography,
  CssBaseline,
  Container,
} from "@mui/material";
import { Combobox } from "./Combobox";
import { AppToolbar, Toolbar } from "./AppToolbar";
import { ThemeProvider } from "./ThemeProvider";

/**
 * The top-level (root) React component.
 *
 * @see https://reactjs.org/
 * @see https://mui.com/core/
 */
export function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <CssBaseline />

      <Container sx={{ my: 2 }}>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          sx={{ mb: 3 }}
          onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
        >
          Open Dialog
        </Button>
        <form
          onSubmit={(evt) => {
            evt.preventDefault();
            alert("Form outside dialog");
          }}
        >
          <Typography variant="h6" component="h1" sx={{ mb: 2 }}>
            Form outside dialog
          </Typography>
          <Stack spacing={2}>
            {/* #region DIALOG */}
            <Dialog open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
              <DialogContent>
                <form
                  onSubmit={(evt) => {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    alert("Form inside dialog");
                  }}
                >
                  <Typography variant="h6" component="h1" sx={{ mb: 2 }}>
                    Form inside dialog
                  </Typography>
                  <Stack spacing={2}>
                    <TextField placeholder="name inside dialog" />
                    <TextField placeholder="email inside dialog" />
                    <Button type="submit" variant="contained">
                      Submit
                    </Button>
                  </Stack>
                </form>
              </DialogContent>
            </Dialog>
            {/* #endregion DIALOG */}
            <TextField placeholder="name outside dialog" />
            <TextField placeholder="email outside dialog" />
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Stack>
        </form>
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

When I open the dialog and submit the form inside the dialog. The form outside dialog will triggered. Is there a way to prevent this?

Visit this link for code reproduction https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-material-ui-typescript-xfv3vu?file=components%2FApp.tsx

Steps to reproduce

- Open dialog
- Submit the form inside dialog
- Two alert will be shown, first alert from `form inside dialog`, and later alert from `form outside dialog`
- 

What I'm expecting is that the `form outside dialog` should not be called, when submitting form inside dialog.

The behavior is unexpected since the `form inside dialog` is rendered in dom in portal, not as child as `form outside dialog`

[image: dom]

1 is root
2 is dialog portal

Comment: If i remember correctly, the `Dialog` isn't designed as a child of your parent, it's child of a `Portal`, therefore by default you won't get any parent/child display layout arrangement. You can try to make second Dialog to be a `div`, then you'll see the behavior you want.

Comment: what do you mean by making second dialog to be a div? Dialog rendered in portal is expected. but the behavior is unexpected. because the `form inside dialog` should not call the `form outside dialog` right?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the stopPropagation event in your submit of your modal

```
<form
              onSubmit={(evt) => {
                evt.preventDefault();
                evt.stopPropagation();
                alert("Form inside dialog");
              }}
            >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) inside the inner form submit (dialog submit):

```js
onSubmit={(evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation(); // <----
  alert("Form inside dialog");
}}
```

Another solution would be to put the dialog outside the outer form. Both solutions are valid.

Comment: is there a downside of stopPropagation?
also why the outside form is called, since `form inside dialog` is not rendered as child of the `form outside dialog`, instead it's rendered in portal

Comment: @BryanLumbantobing No, it is just a common convention to place the dialog outside the main logic. Both solutions are good.

Comment: @BryanLumbantobing the form outside dialog is triggered when the button inside the button inside dialog is clicked because the forms are nested within each other.